# Деформация, анимация картинки на Unity

Tags: unity3d

Хочу анимировать дерево (PNG), чтоб как от ветра сгибалась немножко, как сделать сетку или скелет? Есть такая функция в 2D, по-моему морфинг называется? Или прошу дать ссылку. Мне важно понять как вообще такое делается на Unity.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если совсем не хочется использовать `WindZones` или `Terrain` можно использовать простенький **фрагментный шейдер**.

---

Вот код, который я добавил к стандартному шейдеру спрайтов из юнити:

```
IN.texcoord.x += _SinTime.a*0.05*IN.texcoord.y;
```

---

Логика - сдвигаем текстурную координату по х, сдвиг тем больше, чем выше пиксель. на вход берется синус от времени прошедшего с запуска сцены и умножаем на коэффициент, который по-хорошему надо вынести в настроки шейдера, и тогда в материале будет ползунок.

**За основу взят код шейдера для спрайтов из юнити.**

вот гифка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код целиком:

```js
Shader "wind"
{
 Properties
 {
  [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
  _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
  [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
 }

 SubShader
 {
  Tags
  { 
   "Queue"="Transparent" 
   "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
   "RenderType"="Transparent" 
   "PreviewType"="Plane"
   "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
  }

  Cull Off
  Lighting Off
  ZWrite Off
  Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

  Pass
  {
  CGPROGRAM
   #pragma vertex vert
   #pragma fragment frag
   #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON
   #include "UnityCG.cginc"
   
   struct appdata_t
   {
    float4 vertex   : POSITION;
    float4 color    : COLOR;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
   };

   struct v2f
   {
    float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
    fixed4 color    : COLOR;
    float2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
   };
   
   fixed4 _Color;

   v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
   {
    v2f OUT;
    OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.vertex);
    OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
    OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
    #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
    OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
    #endif

    return OUT;
   }

   sampler2D _MainTex;
   sampler2D _AlphaTex;
   float _AlphaSplitEnabled;

   fixed4 SampleSpriteTexture (float2 uv)
   {
    uv.x;
    fixed4 color = tex2D (_MainTex, uv);

#if UNITY_TEXTURE_ALPHASPLIT_ALLOWED
    if (_AlphaSplitEnabled)
     color.a = tex2D (_AlphaTex, uv).r;
#endif //UNITY_TEXTURE_ALPHASPLIT_ALLOWED

    return color;
   }

   fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
   {
    IN.texcoord.x += _SinTime.a*0.05*IN.texcoord.y;
    fixed4 c = SampleSpriteTexture (IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
    c.rgb *= c.a;
    return c;
   }
  ENDCG
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Класс, благодарствую

Comment: @PinPin наздоровье

Answer (score 2):

Есть встроенный механизм [WindZones](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WindZone.html) , он связан со встроенным же террейном.

Создан он для 3D, но я думаю и вам подойдёт.

Общий смысл в том что вблизи этих зон, спрайты деревьев и травы реагируют на силу и направление ветра.

Для того чтобы это все полетело необходимо сначала добавить в сцену Terrain, затем в настройках добавить спрайты деревьев или травы и после этого можно на террейне будет отметить зоны, где должна расти трава. Ну и про сами WindZone не забудте ;)

Comment: хорошо, попробую, но тэрейт добавлять это даа, неприятно)

Comment: @PinPin если не хочется использовать террейн, предлагаю написать простенький фрагментный шейдер, если вам это интересно я попозже напишу ещё один ответ

Comment: Буду благодарен

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, сколько не думал, так и не понял, почему фрагментный шейдер, если тут проще двигать вершины в вершинном шейдере. Да, нужно будет использовать не обычный quad, но разве это не упростит жизнь как в плане простоты кода, так и в плане производительности?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker мне проще думать категориями пикселей, чем вершин, а по теме, да вы правы, в вершинном тоже можно, но как по мне, так код будет заковыристее, предлагаю сделать по решению и сравнить для интереса

Comment: @RiotBr3aker не знаю как там у вас, но у меня код вершинного шейдера получается сложнее, чем фрагментного. хотя он получается лишен одного недостатка, который есть в принятом ответе - обрезка текстуры за пределами quad-а

Comment: @StrangerintheQ не вижу особого смысла писать решение через вершины, раз автора полностью удовлетворил ваш ответ :) Единственная проблема вершинного подхода - узнать, какая вершина должна двигаться, а какая нет. А подходов таких множество - от цвета вершин до смещения origin'а. Звучит немного муторно, но зато нет проблем с "уходом" пикселей за рамки меши.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker с вершинами мне было сложнее определить высоту относительно rect, а так код примерно такой-же, плюс при таком подходе разный результат получался в окне сцены и окне игры

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да вроде ничего сложного нет прокинуть Vector3 через C#. Через сам шейдер это сделать невозможно, за исключением варианта со сменой origin'а меши. Я бы все это реализовал через quad'ы и цвета вершин - ограничение с фрагментным шейдером выглядят не очень воодушевляюще + цвета вершин позволяют более "тонко" все это дело настроить.